# Почему в этом предложении пишется "вечерней"?

Tags: орфография

...начинал чуть-чуть тревожить докрасна окрашенный **вечерней** зарей горизонт...

Comment: Такое впечатление, что автор делает ошибки намеренно.

Comment: Предложение, как мне кажется, взято вот отсюда: _Однако меня начинал (чуть)чуть тревожить (до)красн… окраше…ый вечерней з…рей г…ризонт предвещающий что мне было (давным)давно известно ветре…ую погоду._ https://znanija.com/task/11246854

Comment: Из-за "авторской" орфографии вопрос и надо бы удалить, отрывок из предложения со множеством ошибок  смотрится не лучшим образом (ошибки надо убрать).  Если вопрос всё-таки редактировать, то лучше оставить такое предложение: Однако меня начинал чуть-чуть тревожить докрасна окрашенный вечерней зарей горизонт.

Answer (score 1):

*Однако меня начинал **чуть-чуть тревожить докрасна окрашенный вечерней зарей горизонт**, предвещающий — что мне было давным-давно известно — ветреную погоду.*
[Русский язык. 5 — 9 классы](https://znanija.com/task/11246854)

Для точного определения ("что с чем согласуется") можно перестроить предложение:

Однако меня начинал чуть-чуть тревожить горизонт, докрасна окрашенный вечерней зарей, предвещающий... ("горизонт" — определяемое слово; "докрасна окрашенный вечерней зарей" — распространенный причастный оборот).

Итак, получаем:
горизонт (какой) окрашенный;
окрашенный (чем?) зарёй (ж. р., Т. п.);
**зарёй** (какой?) **вечерней**.

**Дополнение**
В предложении по смыслу возможно использование и мужского рода для прилагательного, но тогда это будет не *вечерняя заря*, а *вечерний горизонт*.

Структура предложения изменится соответственно:
...тревожить докрасна окрашенный зарёй вечерний горизонт... (здесь причастный оборот — "докрасна окрашенный зарёй").